# "which chapter of that book" vs. "what chapter of that book"

Tags: word-usage

Imagine that, an answer cites a part from a book without telling the chapter.

Should I ask

> "which chapter of that book"?

or

> "what chapter of that book"?

I tried Google Ngram and got no hit.

Google search [gives 9](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&ei=efSMXtiWJMLdmAW09rnoDQ&q=%22what%20chapter%20of%20that%20book%22&oq=%22what%20chapter%20of%20that%20book%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoICAAQCBAHEB5KCggXEgYxMi0xMzRKCAgYEgQxMi04UMEqWNg0YMc4aABwAHgAgAGRAYgBsQmSAQMwLjmYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiYt5HrpNfoAhXCLqYKHTR7Dt0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5) and [10 respectively](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&ei=efSMXtiWJMLdmAW09rnoDQ&q=%22which%20chapter%20of%20that%20book%22&oq=%22which%20chapter%20of%20that%20book%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABgn68DaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiYt5HrpNfoAhXCLqYKHTR7Dt0Q4dUDCAw).

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, "which" is the correct choice. "Which" is used when there are a limited number of choices. "What" is open-ended and is used when there is an unlimited number of possible responses.

"What was that last thing you did today?"

"Which chapter are we supposed to read?"

However, using "what" instead of "which" is fairly common and most people wouldn't think anything of it.

NOTE: The opposite is not true, using "which" when "what" is called for will make for some very awkward sentences. E.g. "Which is your name?" doesn't make sense.